# Why is reduce function outputting no of items in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I'm learning ES6 from a tutorial and while playing with the code, I found something that I didn't understand. The code below outputs '3'.

```
var primaryColors = [

  { color: 'red' },
  { color: 'yellow' },
  { color: 'blue' },

];

var newColors = [];

primaryColors.reduce(function(color, primaryColor){

  return newColors.push(primaryColor.color);

}, []);
```

Why is the return statement returning the no of data in the "stack"?

Comment: Because push returns new length of array.

Comment: It neither changes nor answers your question, but for what it's worth `Array.prototype.reduce` was introduced in [ES5.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.21), not 6.

Comment: @FissureKing actually that tag is misleading - the question has no ES6 code in it, at all.

Comment: Please throw this tutorial away and find a new one. It's bad practice in more than one way.

Comment: What @torazaburo said. There's no "ES6" (that is, ES2015) code above at all, and the ES5 code that's there is...much less than ideal. :-)

Comment: @FissureKing - <pedantry>It was in 5.0 too</pedantry> **;-)**

Comment: The tutorial is actually building up to ES6, so the tutor is first going through some ES5.1 concepts and later into ES6. Since, it was an "ES6 tutorial", I forgot and wrote ES6; my bad.

Comment: @Bik - Hey, fair enough. But again, that ES5 is...odd. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why is reduce function outputting no of items in an array?

[As Nenad Vracar  said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473138/why-is-reduce-function-outputting-no-of-items-in-an-array/50473236#comment87959914_50473138), because `push` returns the number of items in the array, and `reduce` returns the last value the callback returned.

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is not the right tool for this job. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is:

```
var newColors = primaryColors.map(function(primaryColor) {
    return primaryColor.color;
});
```

```js
var primaryColors = [
  { color: 'red' },
  { color: 'yellow' },
  { color: 'blue' },
];
var newColors = primaryColors.map(function(primaryColor) {
    return primaryColor.color;
});
console.log(newColors);
```

or with an ES2015 [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
var newColors = primaryColors.map(primaryColor => primaryColor.color);
```

```js
var primaryColors = [
  { color: 'red' },
  { color: 'yellow' },
  { color: 'blue' },
];
var newColors = primaryColors.map(primaryColor => primaryColor.color);
console.log(newColors);
```

and if we're doing ES2015, we can throw in [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
var newColors = primaryColors.map(({color}) => color);
```

```js
var primaryColors = [
  { color: 'red' },
  { color: 'yellow' },
  { color: 'blue' },
];
var newColors = primaryColors.map(({color}) => color);
console.log(newColors);
```

Comment: Are the parens necessary?  still working on understanding lambdas

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - Yes, you can only leave them off when you have a single, non-destructured, non-defaulted, non-rest parameter. :-)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 (FWIW, I wouldn't call arrow functions *lambdas*. Can a lambda have a name? An arrow function can: `const a = () => {}; console.log(a.name);` logs `"a"` thanks to function name inference (which is specified behavior) and the `Function#name` property. :-) But yeah, loosely...)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for explaining. :)